# FieUpload com Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, file-upload

Pessoal estou com um problema, preciso fazer um update em uma imagem no banco, estou enviando essa imagem com um fileUpload, e tenho um  Ajax.BeginForm ( porque utilizo a chamada ajax para criar abas na minha pagina.), até onde pesquisei sei que com o Ajax.BeginForm não é possível fazer upload, mas qual outra forma eu poderia utilizar para fazer isso então ?

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Comment: Boa tarde, a resposta lhe resolveu o problema? Se sim por favor marque-a como "Correta". Se não diga o que falta. Grato.

Answer (score 2):

Não é um "problema" com o `Ajax.BeginForm`, a questão é que você não pode fazer upload com `XMLHttpRequest` (ajax), para isto você necessitará de `File API` (javascript).

Leia como usar a File API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Um exemplo combinando Ajax e FileAPI, usando Drag e Drop (pegar e soltar o "arquivo na área de transferencia"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dnd binary upload</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendFile(file) {
            var uri = "/index.aspx";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData();

            xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    //Resposta do servidor
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            fd.append('myFile', file);//myFile é a variavel requisitada para o servidor
            // Inicia o upload multipart/form-data
            xhr.send(fd);
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            var dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
            dropzone.ondragover = dropzone.ondragenter = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            dropzone.ondrop = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                var filesArray = event.dataTransfer.files;
                for (var i=0; i<filesArray.length; i++) {
                    sendFile(filesArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="dropzone">Drag & drop o seu arquivo aqui</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar

Comment: @DiegoDias Gostaria de saber se o exemplo lhe ajudou?